# SQL Server: select column names by subquery result

Tags: sql-server

I work with Windows Server 2012 and SQL Server 2021.

I have a query that return me values (result will be 1 column, one or two rows ):

```
query1:select test from Table1
```

I want to select dynamically in the Table 2 the columns which are contained in the result from the first select (literally):

```
query2: select query2 from Table2
```

But I don't find a good method to do. Is it possible?

Comment: *"WS 2012 and sql server 2021."* Are you *sure* about that? 2019 doesn't work on Windows Server 2012, and 2021 hasn't even been announced (yet).

Comment: As for the question, this sounds like you have a design flaw. Sure, this is possible, but such designs are awful to work with at best. A design you not rely on dynamic SQL being needed to use it. This is basically the ending on an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.com).

Comment: A `case` expression would work if the types can be made compatible.

Comment: Could it be you mean SQL Server **2012** (on Win Server 2012) ?? There is no SQL Server **2021** (just yet)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
DECLARE @columns NVARCHAR(MAX);

SELECT @columns = STRING_AGG(QUOTENAME(test), ',')
FROM Table1;

DECLARE @DynamicSQL NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'SELECT ' + @columns + 'FROM table2';
 
EXEC sp_executesql @DynamicSQL
```

Comment: I take it this assumes the OP is really using the as yet unannounced, and unreleased, SQL Server 2012. 